Can't install picos in Python 3.7
I am trying to solve a mathematical problem using python 3.7.0 . For this I've installed CPLEX 12.10 and I decided to install some dependencies, like numpy, prettytable and picos. Numpy and prettytable I get it working normal, but I tried downloading picos (using pip install picos) and didn't work. I get a huge error. How can I fix this?
Collecting picos
  Using cached PICOS-2.4.17-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting cvxopt (from picos)
  Using cached cvxopt-1.3.2.tar.gz (4.1 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\users\gabri\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (from picos) (1.21.6)
Building wheels for collected packages: cvxopt
  Building wheel for cvxopt (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for cvxopt (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [31 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win32-cpython-37
      creating build\lib.win32-cpython-37\cvxopt
      copying src\python\coneprog.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\cvxopt
      copying src\python\cvxprog.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\cvxopt
      copying src\python\info.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\cvxopt
      copying src\python\misc.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\cvxopt
      copying src\python\modeling.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\cvxopt
      copying src\python\msk.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\cvxopt
      copying src\python\printing.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\cvxopt
      copying src\python\solvers.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\cvxopt
      copying src\python\_version.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\cvxopt
      copying src\python\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\cvxopt
      running build_ext
      building 'base' extension
      creating build\temp.win32-cpython-37
      creating build\temp.win32-cpython-37\Release
      creating build\temp.win32-cpython-37\Release\src
      creating build\temp.win32-cpython-37\Release\src\C
      "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Ic:\users\gabri\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\include -Ic:\users\gabri\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\Include "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\cppwinrt" /Tcsrc/C/base.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-cpython-37\Release\src/C/base.obj
      base.c
      "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Ic:\users\gabri\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\include -Ic:\users\gabri\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\Include "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\cppwinrt" /Tcsrc/C/dense.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-cpython-37\Release\src/C/dense.obj
      dense.c
      "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Ic:\users\gabri\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\include -Ic:\users\gabri\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\Include "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\cppwinrt" /Tcsrc/C/sparse.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-cpython-37\Release\src/C/sparse.obj
      sparse.c
      "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\bin\HostX86\x86\link.exe" /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO /LIBPATH:/usr/lib /LIBPATH:c:\users\gabri\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\libs /LIBPATH:c:\users\gabri\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32 /LIBPATH:c:\users\gabri\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\PCbuild\win32 "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\ATLMFC\lib\x86" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\lib\x86" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.22621.0\ucrt\x86" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\lib\10.0.22621.0\\um\x86" m.lib lapack.lib blas.lib /EXPORT:PyInit_base build\temp.win32-cpython-37\Release\src/C/base.obj build\temp.win32-cpython-37\Release\src/C/dense.obj build\temp.win32-cpython-37\Release\src/C/sparse.obj /OUT:build\lib.win32-cpython-37\cvxopt\base.cp37-win32.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win32-cpython-37\Release\src/C\base.cp37-win32.lib
      LINK : fatal error LNK1181: nÆo foi poss¡vel abrir o arquivo de entrada 'm.lib'
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.39.33519\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\link.exe' failed with exit code 1181
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for cvxopt
Failed to build cvxopt
ERROR: Could not build wheels for cvxopt, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Also tried to download the cvxopt (using again the pip install cvxopt) and didn't work. I am pretty new to Python programming (used to program in C#) and I even used this same setup to another problem and worked just fine.
I tried downloading picos (using pip install picos) and didn't work and also tried downloading the cvxopt (using again the pip install cvxopt)

As 3.7 is EOL you might run into issues all the time as people drop support / maintainment of packaging binary-wheels (and without those, compilation from scratch happens which is not easy and leads to errors as above when not working).     Get yourself a modern Python setup! Even numpy, the core-dependency of every kind of scientific software assumes Python >= 3.9.  Yes... this will probably imply a need to update your cplex too!

Based on the installation documentation for CVXOPT on Windows, one of the dependencies for PICOS, it looks like you need the 64-bit version of Python 3.8-3.11 in order to install CVXOPT, but you have Python 3.7.

Wheels for Windows:
are available for Python 3.8-3.11 (64 bit)
are linked against OpenBLAS
include the optional extension GLPK

Perhaps try upgrading to a 64-bit version of Python 3.8 through 3.11 and then try installing PICOS.
